# Why isn't the format of each dataframe changing by date?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, date

I have an ordered dict:

```
OrderedDict([('Sheet1',       name newdate
          0  rob  3-2020
          1     will  2-2020
          2    john  1-2020), ('Sheet2',      name newdate
          0  william  1-2020
          1  tim  2-2020
          2   james  3-2020), ('Sheet3',       name newdate
          0    eric  5-2020
          1  jim  4-2020
          2     evan  6-2020)])
```

I try to run this code in order to change the date column to date format and to get the order of the dataframes from earliest to latest:

```
for sheet, df in company_dict.items():
df['newdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['newdate'])
df = df.sort_values(by="newdate")
```

I get:

```
OrderedDict([('Sheet1',       name    newdate
          0  rob 2020-03-01
          1     will 2020-02-01
          2    john 2020-01-01), ('Sheet2',      name    newdate
          0  william 2020-01-01
          1  tim 2020-02-01
          2   james 2020-03-01), ('Sheet3',       name    newdate
          0    eric 2020-05-01
          1  jim 2020-04-01
          2     evan 2020-06-01)])
```

the dates are in date format but the order in each df didn't change

I'm looking for it to look like:

```
OrderedDict([('Sheet1',       name    newdate
          0  john 2020-01-01
          1     will 2020-02-01
          2    rob 2020-03-01), ('Sheet2',      name    newdate
          0  william 2020-01-01
          1  tim 2020-02-01
          2   james 2020-03-01), ('Sheet3',       name    newdate
          0    jim 2020-04-01
          1  eric 2020-05-01
          2     evan 2020-06-01)])
```

any ideas?

Comment: are you trying to sort the dataframe of the the OrederedDict?

Comment: the orderedDict consists of three dataframes. I am trying to change the order of each data frame by the date column but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Modify the content of the directory as `df` is just a copy of the dataframe

```
for sheet, _ in company_dict.items():
    company_dict[sheet]['newdate'] = pd.to_datetime(company_dict[sheet]['newdate'])
    company_dict[sheet] = company_dict[sheet].sort_values(by="newdate")
```